# Indefinite Integrals Without Differentation and Fundamental Theorem

Tags: calculus, integration

As you know we can solve definite integrals using the definition over limit (without using antiderivatives at all). So I what I ask is how to solve an indefinite integral like that? For example $$\int x^2 \, dx$$ , we all know the result is x^3/3 + c. But we got this by using differentation and Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. How can we calculate this without using them?

Comment: Indefinite integrals are by definition anti-derivatives. There is no direct limit definition for them.

Answer (score 1):

Divide the interval into n parts and use
$\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 =n(n+1)(2n+1)/6
=n^3/3+$ smaller terms.

Take the limit.

This is how these integrals were originally found.

Comment: Can you write the exact limit expression? It seems easy this way but I need it to understand for real.